# Best way of handling entities inheritance in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've three **JPA entity** classes `A`, `B` and `C` with the following hierarchy:

```
    A
    |
+---+---+
|       |
C       B
```

That is:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class A { /* ... */ }

@Entity
public class B extends A { /* ... */ }

@Entity
public class C extends A { /* ... */ }
```

Using **Spring Data JPA**, what is the best way to write **repositories** classes for such entities?

I know that I can write these:

```
public interface ARespository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> { }

public interface BRespository extends CrudRepository<B, Long> { }

public interface CRespository extends CrudRepository<C, Long> { }
```

but if in the class `A` there is a field `name` and I add this method in the `ARepository`:

```
public A findByName(String name);
```

I've to write such method also in the other two repositories, and this is a bit annoying.. Is there a better way to handle such situation?

Another point I would like to have is that `ARespository` should be a read-only repository (i.e. extend the `Repository` class) while the other two repositories should expose all the CRUD operations.

Let me know possible solutions.

Comment: You could write public abstract A findByName(String name), so all subclasses have to implement this method.

Comment: @s.kwiotek but I don't want to implement such method (Spring Data JPA do it for me, with some magic :) ).. I would define it only in one place, like in the `ARespository`..

Comment: One thing I've found with repositories is that *inheritance in the entities does not dictate inheritance in the repositories*. Whereas a Banana is 'a' Fruit, a BananaBox is not a FruitBasket. So to speak. I've had more success having the BananaRepo *use* a FruitRepo through *composition*, accessing it merely for **(A)** the `SELECT` part of the query, and **(B)** populating the base Fruit-properties of the Banana that was just instantiated. You'd have to check if this is possible with Spring, though.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I used the solution also described in [this post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/) from Netgloo's blog.

The idea is to create a *generic* repository class like the following:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ABaseRepository<T extends A> 
extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {
  // All methods in this repository will be available in the ARepository,
  // in the BRepository and in the CRepository.
  // ...
}
```

then I can write the three repositories in this way:

```
@Transactional
public interface ARepository extends ABaseRepository<A> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface BRepository extends ABaseRepository<B> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface CRepository extends ABaseRepository<C> { /* ... */ }
```

Moreover, to obtain a read-only repository for `ARepository` I can define the `ABaseRepository` as read-only:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ABaseRepository<T> 
extends Repository<T, Long> {
  T findOne(Long id);
  Iterable<T> findAll();
  Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);
  Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

and from `BRepository` extend also the Spring Data JPA's `CrudRepository` to achieve a read/write repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface BRepository 
extends ABaseRepository<B>, CrudRepository<B, Long> 
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: In this example can you use use repository B to set attributes belonging to Class A that is extended by Class B?  I wanted to use a system like this to update B via a spring-data-rest controller.

Comment: @ALM I'm pretty sure you can do it. Did you tried it?

Comment: Yes I am about to try right now.  I am actually debating how I want to set it up but I think I will create a very simple test first then run that to see.  I read the other article and after that I believe it should inherit what is for repository A and then be able to be used by B.  A would also be setup as read-only

Comment: @ALM did you find a proper solution? I am also having a similar case where I want the child class repos for writes and the parent class repo just for reads such as GET ALL (including child entities). I also want to do it the way spring-data-rest does it, is there a way?