# Does Spring Data Jpa supports repository inheritance and how to do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a simple entity inheritance tree composed of the following:

```java
abstract class Item (id, ...)
class Chart extends Item (...)
class Table extends Item (...)
```

Each class has its own repository: `ItemRepository`, `ChartRepository` and `TableRepository`. All three repositories are **exposed**.

Because of domain rules, I need to implement custom logic on delete, as explained here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

This custom delete logic concerns all entities in the inheritance tree (the abstract one and the two concretes).

Is there a way to implement custom logic on the `ItemRepository` and make the repositories of the children entities extend `ItemRepository`?

This would avoid duplicate of the same logic for each entity of the inheritance tree. Without that this makes a lot of boilerplate classes :

`EntityRepository` + `EntityRepositoryCustom` + `EntityRepositoryImpl` x `3 entities` = `9 classes` just to implement 1 ligne of code to be executed on delete...

**EDIT**

The answer of user `user7398104` got me on the way to implement things as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549198/5276344) and [there](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/), but theses resources do not explain how to implement a custom repository on the `@NoRepositoryBean` base repository. I tried the following without luck:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ItemBaseRepository<T extends Item> extends 
    CrudRepository<T, Integer>,
    ItemBaseRepositoryCustom<T>

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ItemRepository extends ItemBaseRepository<Item> {}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ChartRepository extends ItemBaseRepository<Item> {}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TableRepository extends ItemBaseRepository<Item> {}

public interface ItemBaseRepositoryCustom<T extends Item> {
    public void delete (T i);
}

public class ItemBaseRepositoryImpl<T extends Item>
    implements ItemBaseRepositoryCustom<T> {

    public void delete (T i) {
        // Custom logic
    }

}
```

**EDIT EDIT**

I tried to set `@NoRepositoryBean` to ItemBaseRepositoryCustom as suggested on comments but it doesnt work either.

Comment: From official Spring Data Commons Ref: [Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is the same link i posted on my question. I know how to create custom repositories implementations but i'm stuck with inheritance.

Comment: Sorry @tiben - damn inattentiveness! (

Comment: @Cepr0 no worry

Comment: You should mention or describe in your question the exact error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ItemRepositoryCustom interface extending the ItemRepository interface, with each chart and table repos extending the ItemRepositoryCustom repo. For this interface you can have a custom implmentation for the delete operation.

**EDIT**: I just realised that this would not work.

But the following approach would work.

`interface CustomItemRepository<T extends Item> extends CrudRepository<T, Long>{ 
}`

`interface ChartRepository extends CustomItemRepository<Chart>{
}`

`interface TableRepository extends CustomItemRepository<Table>{
}`

Then you can create a class for delete logic for CustomItemRepository.

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunatelly it didnt worked. Maybe i did something wrong. I tried with a `ViewRepositoryCustom` interface, a `ViewRepositoryImpl` class, and, for the test, make the `ChartRepository` interface extend `ViewRepositoryCustom`. It only worked once i specialised `ViewRepositoryCustom` and `ViewRepositoryImpl` by simply renaming them `ChartRepositoryCustom` and `ChartRepositoryImpl`. So i doubt it works with abstract entity classes.

Comment: Hi, you edited answer got me on the way but i'm still not able to implement a custom repository. See my edit on the question.

Comment: @NoRepositoryBean this annotation should be on ItemBaseRepositoryCustom repo as this is custom repo and spring should not create proxy class for this as individually it has got no meaning to it.

Comment: this unfortunatelly doesn't change anything.