# Id for Spring Bean/Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository B which I extend from another repository A.

**Repository A:**

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryA implements Repository {

}
```

**Repository  B:**

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryB extends  RepositoryA implements RepositoryAux{
}
```

But when I try to inject the repository I am having the following error:

> No unique bean of type [Repository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [RepositoryA , RepositoryB]

I understand that I can solve it using the annotation @Qualifier. But, my question is:

1. it's right Overwrite the annotation @Repository in the child class ?
2. Can I assign a new identifier to the child class? Instead of using annotation @Qualifier, Something like @Id or @Name

Thank's in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear. --- 1) What do you means by "overwrite" `@Repository`? The `@Qualifier` annotation must be given *in addition to* the `@Repository` annotation, not instead of. --- 2) `@Qualifier` has nothing to do with record/row identifier (field/column).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way of handling entities inheritance in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543771/best-way-of-handling-entities-inheritance-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: FWIW XXXRepository is **nothing** to do with the JPA API, and everything to do with Spring Data JPA. Corrected tagging

Answer (score 3):

> 1. it's right Overwrite the annotation @Repository in the child class ?

There are a few things you should consider:

a. If you intend to use `RepositoryA` as a repository, hen you need `@Repository` on both.

b. If you intent to use `RepositoryA` just to provide basic functionality so `RepositoryB` (or other classes) can extend it, then make `RepositoryA` abstract and annotate with `NoRepositoryBean`

c. Alternatively, you could use "*composition over inheritance*" principle. In short you could inject `RepositoryA` into `RepositoryB` and create facade or wrapper methods to access the methods on `RepositoryB` instance.

> 2. Can I assign a new identifier to the child class? Instead of using annotation @Qualifier, Something like @Id or @Name

I think you mean `@Named` from `javax.inject.Named` which is basically equivalent to `@Qualifier`

I think you mean `<bean id='...'` which in this case `@Qualifier` is the way to do with annotations. See [spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)