# How to implement a hierarchy of types with generics?

Tags: java

Suppose I have 3 classes `Rose`, `Dandelion` & `Tulip`. All of them are extending from the class `Flowers`, which again extends the class `Plant`.
And I have a DataJPA interface that extends from `JpaRepository<???????>`, and has method `save(Entity item)`.

Like this:

```
public class Rose extends Flower {
}
public class Dandelion extends Flower {
}
public class Tulip extends Flower {
}
public class Flower extends Plant {
}
public class Plant implements Persistable<Integer> {
}

public interface CrudFlowerRepository extends JpaRepository<?????????> {

    int delete(int flowerId);

    @Override
    <rerurn object> save(S item);
```

How properly write `CrudFlowerRepository` with generics when need object extends from Flower?

I try write `CrudProductRepository<T, K extends TypedEntity>` and other variants like this `<s extends Plant> save(S item);`. But my attempts failed.
Thank for advice.

Comment: How did you decide your CrudProductRepository parameter as
CrudProductRepository<T, K extends TypedEntity>,  by extending the same logic, you can easily identify the typed methods and classes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Dimitri I just want ......save(new Tulip()) work directly similar as .....save(new Dandelion()). <rerurn object> save(S item); in this place IDEA has warning

Comment: @Timothy How to implement <rerurn object> save(S item);?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543771/best-way-of-handling-entities-inheritance-in-spring-data-jpa